# Can jailbreak iPhone access my app bundle files?

Tags: ios, iphone, security

I would like to store some credential keys in my app to sign requests made to my server and I was wondering where the safest place to store those key is in order to avoid the user to get access to them. I was especially wondering if someone using a jailbreak iPhone can access files stored inside the app bundle.

Comment: The [iOS keychain](http://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password) seems like a suitable place for this kind of info.

Comment: but isn't the keychain accessible by the device user?

Comment: To be quite honest, I've never used it (otherwise I would have posted a thorough answer), but it would be the first thing I researched in your situation.

Comment: Yep I've researched but afaik the keychain is accessible to the user at least on your mac you can access all informations stored in the keychain.

Comment: maybe within the code is the safest

Comment: `you can access all informations stored in the keychain` - I'm sure you can only access information for the *current user*, I can't see the passwords for the other accounts on my machine.

Comment: Though I can't provide technical information to back it up, I'd suggest that if it's the default place for Apple to store sensitive information, it's probably secure enough for you.

Comment: I dont want the current user or any user to be able to access this data. at least minimize the chances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93579/discussion-between-james-webster-and-nicolas-manzini).